# Cleaning up SQL query with nested query and inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

Been trying to reintroduce myself to SQL through some practice questions I've developed for myself, but struggling to find a better way of approaching the following problem:

`playlists`

```
id           title
1            Title1
2            Title2
```

`playlist_clips`

```
id  playlist_id clip_id
1   Title1      3 
2   Title2      1
```

`playlist_tags`

```
playlist_id tag_id
1           1
1           2
2           2
```

`Clips` and `Tags` are two entirely separate tables, and I am using the `playlist_tags` and `playlist_clips` to connect them to the `playlists` table, to represent the two-way one-to-many relationships.

I wanted to select all the playlists that have a given title, and have ALL of the tags provided in the query (in this example [1, 2]), not just "at least one of them".

This is what I've come up with:

```
select p_clips.* from
    (
        select p.id, p.title, count(pc.id) as number_of_clips
        from playlists p
        left join playlist_clips pc on p.id = pc.playlist_id
        where p.title like "Test1"
        group by id
    ) as p_clips

    inner join

    (
        select *
        from playlists p
        left join playlist_tags pt on p.id = pt.playlist_id
        where pt.tag_id in (1, 2)
        group by id
        having count(*) = 2
    ) as p_tags

    on p_clips.id = p_tags.id
```

Whilst, from my testing I've found this to work, it doesn't look particularly elegant, and I also assume it's not terribly efficient performance-wise. (I've removed irrelevant parameters from the code for this example, such as `select` parameters.)

What would be a cleaner way of approaching this, or at the least, a more optimized approach?

`Expected Result`:

```
id  title
260 Title1
```

EDIT: I apologize for my initial confusing post, I've tried to clean up my tables and the information they contain.

Comment: Please fix your sample data. Table `playlists` doesn't have an `id` column. So `on p.id = pc.playlist_id` shouldn't run. Your other tables store titels in `playlist_id` column. Does it make sense? `playlist_tags` table doesn't have a `tag` column. Also please post the expected result.

Comment: I've adjusted my information, and hopefully made it clear that the information from the `playlist_clips` table is required. Please let me know if anything else is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to select all the playlists that have a given title, and have ALL of the tags provided in the query (in this example [1, 2]), not just "at least one of them".

You don't need the clips table at all.  You don't need `left join`s or the `playlists` table in the subquery.

That suggests:

```
select p.*
from playlists p join
     (select pt.playlist_id
      from playlist_tags pt 
      where pt.tag_id in (1, 2)
      group by id
      having count(*) = 2
     ) pt
     on p.id = pt.playlist_id
where p.title like 'Test1';
```

You could phrase this without a subquery as well:

```
select p.*
from playlists p join
     playlist_tags pt 
     on p.id = pt.id
where p.title like 'Test1' and
      pt.tag_id in (1, 2)
group by p.id
having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do need, the clips query - as I mentioned I removed superfluous information, and playlist_clips has an entirely different data structure, and information that I would like to return from it. (For example, counting the number of clips, and the total length of them together)

I will make an adjustment to my post such that you can see the information more clearly - apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @TTBDV . . . You may need clips under other circumstances, but not to answer the question that you have asked here.  Of course, if you want to filter by it, you can add it as a `JOIN` in either of these queries.

Comment: What I'm implying is, that with my original query I need the playlist_clips table to be joined in as well to extract information from it. if I simply add another join after the join you placed in the second query, that would provide me with duplicate, and inaccurate results.

Comment: @TTBDV . . . That's nice.  Your **question** uses no information from the clips table.  The query does not return columns from that table.  The table is not needed for filtering.  If you have *another question* that involves that table, then ask that as a *new question*.

Comment: I will ask a new question, but it will contain virtually all the text from this question with just a minor addition. Thank you for your help.