# Cleaning up SQL query with nested query and inner join [Rephrase]

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

Been trying to reintroduce myself to SQL through some practice questions I've developed for myself, but struggling to find a better way of approaching the following problem:

`playlists`

```
id  title
1   Title1
2   Title2
```

`playlist_clips`

```
id  playlist_id clip_id
1   Title1      3 
2   Title2      1
```

`playlist_tags`

```
playlist_id tag_id
1           1
1           2
2           2
```

`Clips` and `Tags` are two entirely separate tables, and I am using the `playlist_tags` and `playlist_clips` to connect them to the `playlists` table, to represent the two-way one-to-many relationships.

I wanted to select all the playlists that have a given title, and have ALL of the tags provided in the query (in this example [1, 2]), not just "at least one of them"; additionally, I want to query information from the playlist_clips table, including the number of clips, total playlist duration, etc.

This is what I've come up with:

```
select p_clips.* from
    (
        p.id, p.title, CAST(COALESCE(sum(pc.duration_seconds), 0) as UNSIGNED) as total_duration_in_seconds, count(pc.id) as number_of_clips
        from playlists p
        left join playlist_clips pc on p.id = pc.playlist_id
        where p.title like "Test1"
        group by id
    ) as p_clips

    inner join

    (
        select *
        from playlists p
        left join playlist_tags pt on p.id = pt.playlist_id
        where pt.tag_id in (1, 2)
        group by id
        having count(*) = 2
    ) as p_tags

    on p_clips.id = p_tags.id
```

Whilst, from my testing I've found this to work, it doesn't look particularly elegant, and I also assume it's not terribly efficient performance-wise. (I've removed irrelevant parameters from the code for this example, such as `select` parameters.)

What would be a cleaner way of approaching this, or at the least, a more optimized approach?

`Expected Result`:

```
id  title
260 Title1
```

EDIT: I apologize for my initial confusing post, I've tried to clean up my tables and the information they contain.

Comment: I want to emphasize that this is different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59018101/cleaning-up-sql-query-with-nested-query-and-inner-join/59018167#comment104282860_59018167 because this version explicitly brings in the clips table.

Comment: . . Your sample data is probably a poor choice because you have only one clip per playlist id.  I suspect you really want more.  The expected result should include the clips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want summary information from both the clips and the playlist:

```
select p.*
from playlists p join
     (select pt.playlist_id
      from playlist_tags pt 
      where pt.tag_id in (1, 2)
      group by id
      having count(*) = 2
     ) pt
     on p.id = pt.playlist_id join
     (select pc.playlist_id, group_concat(pc.clip_id) as clips
      from playlist_clips pc
      group by pc.playlist_id
     ) pc
     on p.id = pc.playlist_id
where p.title like 'Test1';
```

Note:  This puts all the clip information into one column.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I much prefer the structure of your solution, and again apologies for the messiness of the previous post.

Comment: @TTLife . . . I can see that you put effort into asking the questions.  Asking a good question can be rather tricky.  You have to not only be clear about what you want, but about conveying the right information to people who have no familiarity with your data or problem.